# classify one word using RNN

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

I would classify just one word if it's real name or not, I used LSTM layers but
I read that LSTM is used when we have sequences, but in my case I don't have any sequences, it's just one word I don't have experience in deep learning can anyone give me a track and the best model can handle with this type of problem I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine you need a model for this, but maybe I don't understand your situation. Have you considered something like the name corpus from nltk? If you are using Python, consider

https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/nltk/nltk-corpus-exercise-11.php